# Constant Runtime Error -Python - Tkinter

Tags: function, class, tkinter, runtime-error, bind

My problem here is that I get a Runtime Error every time I run my code. Also, I am unable to bind my "Repeat" button with the "RUN" function. I do not understand why the button will not work and I am also unsure why the "self.canvas.delete()" does not work and why the new frame does not open when the puzzle has been solved (when all of the disks have been moved to a new pole) and why it opens straight away.

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
import time

def Hanoi(n, src, dst, tmp, move):

    if n == 0:
        return n

    else:

        Hanoi(n-1, src, tmp, dst, move)
        move(src, dst)
        Hanoi(n-1, tmp, dst, src, move)



class hanoi():

    master = Tk()
    width = 2000
    height = 400
    time = 0.1
    big_sep = 30
    small_sep = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.User_Input = input("Please enter the amount of disks")
        self.canvas = Canvas(hanoi.master, height = hanoi.height, width = hanoi.width)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.poles = [[], [], []]
        self.Add_Objects()


    def Add_Objects(self):

        floor_size = 1000-2*hanoi.small_sep
        self.disk_height = (400 - 4*hanoi.big_sep) / self.User_Input
        self.disk_width = (floor_size - 4*hanoi.small_sep) / 3
        disk_h = self.disk_height
        disk_w = self.disk_width
        global disk_h
        global disk_w
        width = hanoi.width
        height = hanoi.height
        small_sep = hanoi.small_sep
        big_sep = hanoi.big_sep

        #create poles
        bar_pos = [ 4*small_sep + disk_w/2 + (disk_w+small_sep)*i for i in range(0,3) ]
        for x in bar_pos:
            print x

            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-small_sep, big_sep, x+small_sep, 400-big_sep-1, fill='black')


        #create bases
        for x in bar_pos:
            print i
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-(13*small_sep), 370, x+(13*small_sep), 410, fill = "brown")


        #create disks
        for i in range(self.User_Input):
            print 2*small_sep + 4*small_sep*i, height-big_sep-1-disk_h*i,2*small_sep + disk_w - 4*small_sep*i, height-big_sep-1-disk_h*(i+1)
            disk = self.canvas.create_rectangle(2*small_sep + 4*small_sep*i, 400-big_sep-1-disk_h*i,2*small_sep + disk_w - 4*small_sep*i, 400-big_sep-1-disk_h*(i+1),fill='blue')
            self.poles[0].append(disk)


        self.canvas.update()





    def Move_Object(self, origin, dest):
        print len(self.poles[dest]), self.User_Input-1

        current_disk = self.poles[origin].pop()
        self.poles[dest].append(current_disk)

        x_distance = (dest - origin) * (disk_w)
        y_distance = ((len(self.poles[origin]) - len(self.poles[dest])+1) * disk_h)

        self.canvas.move(current_disk, x_distance, y_distance)
        self.canvas.update()
        time.sleep(hanoi.time)

        if len(self.poles[dest]) == self.User_Input:
            self.canvas.delete()

            new_frame = Frame(hanoi.master, width = 300, height = 300)
            new_frame.pack()
            print "Yayar"
            newb = Button(new_frame, text = "Replay", )
            newb.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5)
            newb.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.RUN)


    def RUN(self):
        Hanoi(self.User_Input, 0, 2, 1, self.Move_Object)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "hello"
    hanoi().RUN()
```

Comment: please clean up the formatting of your code. It's a mess, and the code can't be run as-is.

Comment: That should be better

Comment: The code can now be run, feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: `hanoi.py:42: SyntaxWarning: name 'disk_h' is assigned to before global declaration    global disk_h`seems pretty self explanatory to me. Move global statements to the beginning of method to get rid of it. For other problems, please create small examples exhibiting your problem and create dedicated questions.